# My IDLE script is returning a weird error

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm messing around with idle and wrote a silly program:

```
name = "none"
phone = "none"
while phone == "none":
     phone = str(input("Please enter your phone number formatted as (111)111-111 "))
print("loading...")
while name == "none":
    name = str(input("Please enter your full name formatted as First, Last "))
print("Thank you for entering your information. Is this correct?")
print("Phone: ", phone, "Name: ", name)
yesno = str(input("Please Enter 'yes', or 'no' to confirm this information."))
if yesno == "yes":
    print("Thank you for your time! Your data has been successfully submitted.")
else:
    print("Sorry. Please reload the program and enter your data again")
```

but when I run it I get the error: Unexpected EOF.

It seems to work when I only use numbers and no punctuation. Why cant I pass punctuation like (), in my code?

Comment: Are you sure you are not actually using Python 2.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running your code in Python2, where `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. So, it is going to throw EOF errors for [invalid identifiers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

```
>>> input()
1sdfsdf
  File "<string>", line 1
    1sdfsdf
          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

So, either run your code in Python3 or use `raw_input` for Python2.(Note that the `str` call is redundant if you're going to use Python3.)

Comment: I have both 2.75 and 3.3.2 installed. I am running IDLE 3.3.2 though. Could both installed be causing an issue?

Comment: @user2994925 I don't think so, try to run the script through shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 test.py
Please enter your phone number formatted as (111)111-111 555 555 5555
loading...
Please enter your full name formatted as First, Last joe, schmoe
Thank you for entering your information. Is this correct?
Phone:  555 555 5555 Name:  joe, schmoe
Please Enter 'yes', or 'no' to confirm this information.yes
Thank you for your time! Your data has been successfully submitted.
```

So, it works fine as in in py3.