# unexpected EOF while parsing ???

Tags: python

So i was trying to create a simple calculator and i thought that there isn't anything wrong with this code but when i ran the code, it said that there's SyntaxError : unexpected EOF while parsing ([string], line 1)  and i tried several changes but i still can't see the mistake, please help me??

```
operation = input ("Pick your operation:  +  |  -  |  *  |  /   ")

    if operation == '+' :
        no1 = int(input ("Pick a number"))
        no2 = int(input ("Pick another number"))
        answer = no1 + no2
        print ( "Answer:", no1 , "+" , no2 , "=", answer)

    elif operation == '-':
        no1 = int(input ("Pick a number"))
        no2 = int(input ("Pick another number"))
        answer = no1 - no2
        print ( "Answer:", no1 , "-" , no2 , "=" , answer)

    elif operation == '*':
        no1 = int(input ("Pick a number"))
        no2 = int(input ("Pick another number"))
        answer = no1 * no2
        print ( "Answer:", no1 , "*" , no2 , "=", answer)

    elif operation == '/':
        no1 = int(input ("Pick a number"))
        no2 = int(input ("Pick another number"))
        answer = no1 / no2
        print ( "Answer:", no1 , "/" , no2 , "=", answer)

    else:
        print ("Please check your given options of operations.")
```

Comment: What version of Python, 2 or 3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My IDLE script is returning a weird error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080386/my-idle-script-is-returning-a-weird-error)

Answer (score 2):

Your line is valid, both in Python 2 and 3 but it makes sense in Python 3 only.

There has been a change in the behavior of input between versions.

In Python 2 you have to use `raw_input` instead:

```
operation = raw_input("Pick your operation:  +  |  -  |  *  |  /   ")
```

Read the docs at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input and https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `raw_input` for python versions < 3.0. You may want to check [behavior of input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)